# how to fix following errors. (React, IIS)

Tags: html, reactjs, iis, plesk

I created small web page, but struggle to set it up correctly. When i try to run i locally
i get following error.[image]

when i run it with directory browsing it shows me this [image]

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged IIS and not react?

Comment: select the build folder as the site folder path

Comment: I don't know what guide you were following to publish this React web app to IIS, but the steps were wrong badly. Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for tutorials. You still need to use search engines. But a few hints: 1) there needs to be a rewrite rule to forward URLs to index page. 2) the IIS web site should point to the actual output folder of React build, so that the artifacts can be loaded properly.